# Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Tags: c, консоль, cmd, printf, scanf

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {

   double number;
   char alphabet;


   printf("Enter double input: ");
   scanf("%if", &number);


   printf("Enter character input: ");
   scanf("\n%c", &alphabet);

   printf("Number: %if, number");
   printf("\nCharacter: %c", alphabet);

   return 0;
}
```

[image: 1] Это из урока.

[image: 2] Это мой код и вывод.

При компиляции ошибок нет, но результат другой.

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `%if` на `%lf`...

Comment: Спасибо что уделили мне время, хоть я не понял в чем ошибка но методом тыка все встало на свои места.

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вы указали неверный спецификатор формата. `%if` - это целое число, за которым следует символ `f`, `%lf` — тип `double`.

Comment: надо проверять, что возвращает scanf, тогда будет понятно, что какая-то ошибка произошла...

Comment: Спасибо что уделили мне время, хоть я не понял в чем ошибка но методом тыка все встало на свои места.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как писали выше, проблема была в том, что в `scanf` пытался считать неверный спецификатор формата `%if` .

---

В примере из-за шрифта может показаться, что это `%if`, хотя там на самом деле `%lf`, чак что просто замените один символ)
Почитайте про спецификаторы формата- как в С называть разные типы данных, грубо говоря. Ну и про сами типы данных.
Вот удобная шпаргалка по теме:
[image: шпора по спецификаторам формата С]

УДАЧИ

Comment: Многовато ошибок в шпаргалке. Например, `%i` — это `int`, а не `unsigned int`; `%l` — ошибочный спецификатор, а не `long`; `%lu` — это `unsigned long`, а не `unsigned int`. Лучше сразу смотреть [документацию на cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).